# Transferring file over network

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm transferring a file (an image) over the network, from a pc to an android. The server code is:

```
int offset = 0;
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(requested));
byte[] temp = new byte[300];
int len;
while((len = bis.read(temp)) > 0){
    byte[] data;
    if(len == temp.length){
        data = temp;
    }
    else{
        data = new byte[len];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, data, 0, len);
    }
    writer.println(Base64.encode(data));
}
bis.close();
```

and the client receiving it (the android):

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(input, Base64.NO_WRAP);
fos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

(the fos variable being a buffered output stream with a file output stream)

The file arrives, and the size of it is the same as the one that was sent, however, when the file is opened on the android, the image app displays a black screen.

**EDIT: All .GIF seem to open fine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sending a folder would send multiple files, when a new file started being sent, the input stream for the previous was closed to open one for the new one, however the final file downloaded's input stream was never closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is doing multiple base64 encode on sending side and one decode on receiving side.

Its worth ensuring that only one encode happens on complete file while sending.
And only one decode happens on receiving side.

Later on you can try with N encodes and N decodes.